# Create a regular graph through one vertex deletion

Tags: c, algorithm, graph

The problem: Given an undirected graph, implemented using adjacency list. I'm looking for an algorithm to transform it to a regular graph (each vertex has same degree) through one vertex deletion.

For example:

[image: example]

Comment: Please specify if it should be C or C++ with one tag. These could be different.

Comment: Your example has two solutions. Should your algorithm find all solutions or just any solution?

Comment: @IanAbbot, one solution is enough

Comment: I suppose the obvious solution is to iterate through each vertex in turn and check whether removing it would leave the other vertices connected  and with an equal number of edges.

Answer (score 1):

Iterate all vertex, partition them by their degrees.

If all have same degree, its only possible if there is a vertex that has degree n - 1.

If you can partition them into 2 different degrees set: Let´s call X the set with the lower degree and Y the one with higher. Lets call dg(X) and dg(Y) the degree of those vertex

- If one of the partitions has only 1 vertex and its degree is either 0 or the amount of vertex in the other set, remove it
- If dg(Y) - dg(X) > 1, its not possible
- If dg(Y) - dg(X) = 1 and |Y| = dg(X), check if a vertex from X is connected to all vertex from Y and remove it.
- If dg(Y) - dg(X) = 1 and |X| = dg(Y), check if a vertex from Y is connected to all vertex from X and remove it.
- Any other case is not possible with 2 partitions

If you can partition into 3 sets:

- One of them must have only 1 vertex and that vertex has to be connected to all vertex from the other highest degree set, and to none of the remaining set. The degree difference between the other highest degree set and the remaining set must also be 1

Any other case, its not possible